# Неудается считать числа с файла

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы

Нужно считать из некого файла массив целых чисел (неизвестной размерности), выделить под него память и представить это в виде матрицы. Код должен быть максимально компактен, поэтому я решил не считывать данные как строку, а потом конвертировать её в числа.

```
int main() 
{

    ifstream infile("array.txt");
    int n, counter = 0, **p;
    while (!infile.eof()) {
        counter++;
    }

    counter = sqrt(counter);
    cout << "counter is " << counter << endl;
    p = new int*[counter];

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        p[i] = new int[counter];

    while (!infile.eof()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
                p[i][j] = n;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++) {
        cout << p[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Вот мой код, он сделан под квадратную матрицу, т.к. пока что не нашёл более верного способа для определения размерности матрицы. Проблема в том, что в первый раз я условно определяю размерность для массива, а во второй раз мне не удается ничего считать.

Comment: После того как вы поток до конца прочитали, файловый указатель остается в конце и конечно ничего за концом не читается. Вам надо опять вернуть его на начало. С ifstream не знаком, так что не знаю как, но скорее всего должен быть какой нибудь seek или на худой конец переоткрыть файл заново

Comment: Данная программа и не пытается что-то считать из файла. Для объекта `infile` вызывается только `eof()`, которая чтение не производит.

Comment: @sercxjo 
while (!infile.eof()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
                p[i][j] = n;
        }
    }
здесь я пытался выделенному участку памяти значение из файла

Comment: ну и где заполняется переменная `n`?

Comment: @sercxjo не подскажите, как переместить значение переменной н на начало файла?

Comment: `infile.seekg(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Числа не читаются из файла, потому что на момент заполнения матрицы достигнут конец файла (при подсчете размерности). Кроме того, даже попыток прочитать что-либо из файла нет.
Мне кажется, логично предположить, что, если в файле хранится матрица, то в ней должно быть N строк и M столбцов. Таким образом, можно считывать данные из файла построчно.
Чтобы не мучиться с выделением памяти, можно воспользоваться стандартным вектором как хранилищем для каждой строки матрицы и представить всю матрицу как вектор таких же векторов.
Согласно [документации](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) чтение из ifstream может быть произведено разными способами. Можно вычитывать сразу число с помощью оператора >>. Можно вычитать сразу строку с помощью getline() и распарсить ее в вектор чисел.

При таком подходе не придется довольно странным способом определять размерность (не факт, что она в вашем случае будет правильной).